# 1120: Access of undefined property speed.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, variables

I want to change a var which is located in another class.
I got the class c_wall.as which contains this code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


public class c_wall extends c_gameObject {
    public var speed:Number=10;

    public function c_wall() {








    }
    override public function update(){
        x-=speed;

    }
}

}
```

This class is the parent of my wall child which is a object that moves over the screen whit 10px each frame (the value of my var speed)

In the main class I got the following code to change the speed var:

```
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

        faster.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);

        function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
        {
            trace ("the speed has increased");
            speed++;//this is the speed he doesnt know

        }
```

Now I get the error that it doesnt know the var speed

I think the solution is to include the var with the update(); function. which gets used in the main as file too like this:

```
                function onEnterFrame(evt:Event):void
                {

                    wall.update(;

                    player.update();


                }
```

But I wont get it to work... anyone knows a solution?

Greetings,
Merijn

Comment: where is speed declared - and show the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `TouchEvent` listener in the main class, remove the line where it tries to access the `speed` variable. Then, in the `c_wall` class, where the `speed` variable is defined, override the event listener callback function and manipulate the variable.

In the main class:

```
protected function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void {
    //Do things relevant to the main class
}
```

In the `c_wall` class:

```
override protected function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void {
    super.fl_TapHandler(event); //Pass along the event to the parent 
    speed++;
}
```

Of course, if you're not using the event listener at all in the main class, you could always move it down the inheritance chain to the `c_wall` class and skip the override.

Comment: will try that if I'm at work tomorrow! sounds legit! I figured out it also might be the update function which is a ovveride of the parent. When I change the update function it might not ovveride it anymore which gave me an error before. thanx anyway!